# Как изменить углы у кнопки в Android

Tags: android, android-button

Хочу изменить углы у кнопки. Для этого в качестве бэкграунда передаю ей файл shape.xml (android:background="@drawable/shape"). Но я получаю ошибку "Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed". Никак не могу решить, помогите пожалуйста.  Вот содержимое файла shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <corners
        android:radius="3dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Метка `android-studio` используется для вопросов связанных только с самой IDE, а не с тем что вы там создаете. Поэтому в вам бы посоветовал избегать использования неправильных меток, поскольку здесь это не приветствуется :))

Answer (score 2):

Создание кнопки с закругленными углами это довольно распространенный вопрос. Вот что я вам посоветую сделать:

1. Так как у вас возникла проблема с применением стиля для вашей кнопки, значит у вас уже есть кнопка. Я думаю что вы и так знаете, но все же напишу, что у кнопки должен быть такой атрибут: `android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"`.
2. Вторым пунктом будет создание того самого `drawable` файла который будет фоном для вашей кнопки. У вас все хорошо но я бы вам посоветовал углы создавать таким образом:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <solid android:color="#0d0524" />
       <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
           android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
           android:topRightRadius="10dp"
           android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
   </shape>
   ```

   Закругленные углы задаются с помощью тега corners и его атрибутов `bottomRightRadius`, `bottomLeftRadius`, `topRightRadius` и `topLeftRadius`. Чем больше числовое значение этих атрибутов, тем больше закругление углов имеет кнопка.

   [Первоисточник](http://androiddocs.ru/programmnoe-sozdanie-knopki-s-zakruglennymi-uglami/)

Надеюсь что помог вам в решении вашего вопроса. Удачи :)

Comment: Увы , вы мне не помогли. Ваш код приводит к той же ошибке

Comment: проблема однако))) может кто еще заметит у вас ошибку, я тоже подумаю тогда)