# Никак не закруглить углы у кнопки

Tags: android

хочу создать круглую кнопку, но при использовании любого атрибута у тега corners, возникает следующая ошибка:

Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed.

Помогите разобраться, что это за ошибка и как все-таки закруглить углы кнопке.

Comment: Покажите код...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881450/Как-изменить-углы-у-кнопки-в-android   тот же вопрос, но с кодом

Comment: Не нужно задавать "тот же вопрос"! Там уже есть ответ. Если он не решает проблему, то так и напишите там в комментариях.